# I am using iOS' prefetching to download images for tableview, but why is the display still jerky?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewdatasourceprefetching

I have an app which fetches RSS feeds and then uses image URLs from those feeds to download and populate an ImageView. I had a go at implementing iOS prefetching (see code below), but it's still glitchy, like it pauses briefly when scrolling (even when scrolling at a 'reasonable speed). I'm not sure what the best way is to debug this - any advice?

This is the TableViewController's `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
    if let item = rssItems?[indexPath.item] {
        cell.item = item
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.descriptionText.text = item.isExpanded ? item.description : ""
        cell.descriptionText.isHidden = item.isExpanded ? false : true 
        cell.delegate = self
        if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UIImageView {
            if (rssItems![indexPath.row].imageData != nil) {
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: item.getImageData()!)
            } else {
                imageView.image = nil
                if cell.item.imageLink == "" {
                    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    imageView.image = UIImage(named:item.logoImage!)
                    
                } else {
                    if let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: cell.item.imageLink!) {
                        cell.item.imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
                        imageView.image = UIImage(data: cell.item.imageData!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Here is the prefetching extension (I didn't implement the cancel download part):

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching
extension NewsTableViewController: UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        //        print("prefetchRowsAt \(indexPaths)")
        indexPaths.forEach { self.rssItems![$0.row].setImageData() }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        //        print("cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt \(indexPaths)")
        //        indexPaths.forEach { self.cancelDownloadingImage(forItemAtIndex: $0.row) }
    }
}
```

Then the `setImageData` function comes from a class which makes up an object representing a feed item along with the URL to the image for the given cell:

```
func setImageData() {
    if self.imageLink != nil {
        guard let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: self.imageLink!) else {
            return
        }
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) else {
          return
        }
        self.imageData = imageData
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefetching does not, in and of itself, solve the problem of downloading data in order to fill out a table view. You cannot network directly in `cellForRowAt`, as it needs to supply the cell immediately or you will not be able to scroll. You must kick off the networking if the data is missing, and then, when the data arrives, you reload the data and this time `cellForRowAt` finds the data and displays it (immediately).

Comment: Also note that prefetching does not, in and of itself, do anything for the initially visible cells when the table view first appears.

Comment: Also, read the [note here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init). - Do not use `Data(contentsOf:)` for network operations. You need to use a `URLSessionTask` or, (and I highly recommend this if you are willing to accept external dependencies) use a framework like SDWebImage or Kingfisher